# Removing the home screen number to have one more row of app shortcuts

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Is there any way to remove the home screen "numbers", i.e. (red rectangle):

[image: Screenshot]

and instead have one more row of app shortcuts?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Hi Franck, it might help to add what launcher you are using. I've never seen the like; all launchers I've ever used at maximum showed that as overlay when swiping to another home screen.

Comment: @Izzy I'm using the default launcher (Samsung's Stock Launcher).

Comment: Ah, thanks. My comment just "overlapped" with GiantTree's answer ;) I second his suggestion for an alternative launcher. As we don't recommend apps here, I don't tell you to take a look at Apex and Nova launcher ;)

Comment: Any time, Franck! For more alternatives, please take a look at my list of [Home Replacements](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher) :) I'm using Apex myself, so that's something I can really recommend. And Nova is said to almost be a twin of it when it comes to the paid versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on Samsung's Stock Launcher but many alternative launchers have the possibility to display even more rows by shrinking them in height.

Try a third-party launcher as nearly all Samsung stock applications tend to be unoptimized for any Samsung device; especially in memory consumption.

---

E.g. using [Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime&hl=en) you can remove the scroll indicator as follows:

[image]

Result (the number of rows and columns of the desktop grid can be changed as you want):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendation for alternative launchers?

Comment: *Nova Launcher* and *Apex Launcher* (as Izzy recommended) are full of custom features including the one you are asking for.

Comment: I *suggested,* we don't recommend apps here – ah wait: we just don't permit explicitly *asking* for, so OK #D